React app translations most common and scalable way
We have started working on translating our web app for multiple languages and the problem that I see is that we have to store the translations in several places. We have created a folder for individual languages in our codebase and on top of that we have to have a spreadsheet where all the texts are listed so that translators can translate them.
I feel like it's not very scalable. In order for us to add a simple text, we have to find the associated file in our codebase, add the text there, go to the spreadsheet and add the text again for the translators.
How do we combine them to ensure we don't have to worry about adding new texts in 2 places. How are you guys handling it for your codebase?
